# jquery.ui.spinner change

Tags: jquery, events, user-interface, spinner, onchange

I'm trying to use the latest version of the jquery.ui.spinner.js . http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138077/Spinner

The spinners are showing-up and updating the textboxes, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to capture the 'change' event. It triggers when you manually change the value in the textbox, but not when you use the spinner arrows.

jquery:

```
    $('input[name*="opening"]').spinner({ min: 0, max: 100});

    $('#doorsize6w7h-f').spinner().change(function(){
         alert($(this).spinner('value'));
    });
```

html:

```
<input type="text" value="0" class="front" id="doorsize6w7h-f" name="opening[0][0]" />
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Attach an event on the spinner controls that calls `change()` on your textbox.

```
$('.ui-spinner-button').click(function() {
   $(this).siblings('input').change();
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/LYe2P/1/).

After setting up the spinner.

Comment: Is the call to the change event not correct in my jquery example? That id has a spinner attached to it from the statement above. I only get the alert when I type a new number in the textbox.

Comment: @phil planes I don't think it would register the `change()` like that, but I have no experience using this either. I would inspect the tool with Firebug, figure out its elements, and then hook the `click()` event to that.

Comment: +1, I'm pretty sure that you've got the right idea with simply firing the input's `change` event in the spinner's change handler.

Comment: I'm relatively new to jq and little confused. Can you give an example?

Comment: @phil planes If you can show me an example, perhaps on http://jsFiddle.com, I'll be able to give you exact code.

Comment: @ alex I'm a little new to jsfiddle too, but hopefully this will work: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/etriad/LYe2P/)

Comment: @phil planes Awesome, see update, I have working code for you.

Comment: @alex ... I think I messed-up your update by clicking 'Update' in jsfiddle. I'm sorry, but can you show me the code again? Also, how do I see the changes you've made?

Comment: @alex ... never mind. I see the changes in your answer. I'm confused all over the place.

Comment: @phil planes Check the fiddle - does it do what you want it to now?

Comment: This only raises the change event when you let go of the mouse, which works, but creates janky results for my usage case.

Comment: Obviously this will not work when the user uses the mouse wheel

Answer (score 20):

I think this is what you need:

```
$('.mySpinner').spinner({          
    stop:function(e,ui){
        alert('Triggered after a spin.');
    }
});
```

Unlike binding to the `click` event of the buttons, this will also detect use of the up/down keys on the keyboard.

See this page for details and more events:
http://api.jqueryui.com/spinner/#entry-examples

Comment: The problem with the `stop` event is that, as per the docs, even though the `ui` object is available, it's empty, so you can't get the value of the spinner immediately after a spin. That's why I prefer using the `spin` event.

Answer (score 11):

There is no "change" event, instead use "spinstop" event:

```
$('#doorsize6w7h-f').on("spinstop", function(){
   alert($(this).spinner('value'));
});
```

The documentation also suggests **spinchange** event, but it's kind of laggy for me.

Resource: http://api.jqueryui.com/spinner/?rdfrom=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.jquery.com%2Fmw%2Findex.php%3Ftitle%3DUI%2FSpinner%2Fspinner%26redirect%3Dno#event-change

Comment: This is what I used and it worked best for me.  It takes care of the mouse click and keyboard event.

Answer (score 7):

Well, actually I would route changes through standard 'change' event and capture everything, like that:

```
$('input[name*="opening"]').spinner({
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    spin: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).change();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

This is giving me the most fluid results:

```
function betterSpinner(input)
{
    input.spinner(
    {
        spin: function(event, ui)
        {
            // the spin event is raised before the value actually gets changed,
            // so let's update it here before raising the input's change() event.
            input.val(ui.value);
            input.change();
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function ()
{
    betterSpinner($("#myInput"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question has already been answered. But I hope this will help others.

Beside manually edit the value and using the spinner's arrow button, one can also edit the value of spinner by using arrow button on keyboard. In this case, I find keyup event is more robust than change event:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var range_spinner = $('.spinner').spinner(); 

    // hack to trigger input keyup whenever spinner button clicked:
    $('.ui-spinner-button').click(function() { $(this).siblings('input').keyup(); });   

    // keyup will catch any stroke on keyboard
    $('#range').keyup(function(){
       console.log(range_spinner.spinner('value')); 
    });
});
```