# get spinner ui value on change

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

How could  get the value of a spinner when the value is changing with the button up and down?

```
<input type="text" id="spinner1" value="1" onchange="selFirt()" readonly>
<script>
    $("#spinner1").spinner({min: 1, max: 5});
function selFirt(){
    $('#spinner1').spinner().change(function(){
        alert($(this).spinner('value'));
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: what's .spinner() ???

Comment: A spinner enhance a text input for entering numeric values, with up/down buttons and arrow key handling.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('input[name*="name"]').spinner({
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    spin: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).change();
    }
});
```

[**SEE HERE**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5149830/jquery-ui-spinner-change)

Comment: Why you need to convert into function

Comment: because I'll it with a lot of inputs

Answer (score 2):

try the following :

```
$(function () {
    var spinner = $("#spinner").spinner({
        step: 2 ,
        spin: function( event, ui ){
            handleSpinnerValue(ui.value);
        }
    });
});
function handleSpinnerValue(txtValue)
{
    //do here whatever you want with the value;
    alert(txtValue);
}
```

Comment: Thx for pointing out the usage of ui argument. However in the blur(handler) event you have to use `this`