# Conditional styling of an HTML <input> based on current value

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui

I'm trying to customize the color of an `<input>` element based on it's current value.

So far I've tried solutions based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39165486/how-can-i-apply-style-to-a-div-based-on-condition-in-thymeleaf) or this [post](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000097oYIAQ), but can't get it to work even for a simple condition (e.g. "1<2"), and so even less based on the input's value (e.g. "value<2").

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sc28/vtfqW/354/) illustrating the problem, and my attempts below:

```
    <p>
Simple coloring
      <input autocomplete="off" id="spinner-twenty"  style="background-color:red" class="spinner-twenty" name="spinner" value="0.1">
    </p>

    <p>
Conditional coloring based on style condition
      <input autocomplete="off" id="spinner-twenty"  style="${1} < 2 ? 'background-color:red' : 'background-color:white'" class="spinner-twenty" name="spinner" value="0.1">
    </p>

    <p>
   Conditional coloring based on background-color condition

      <input autocomplete="off" id="spinner-twenty"  style="background-color:{!IF(1 < 4,'#7CFC00', '#FFA07A')}" class="spinner-twenty" name="spinner" value="0.1">
    </p>    

  Conditional coloring based on background-color condition (based on inputs "value")

      <input autocomplete="off" id="spinner-twenty"  style="background-color:{!IF(value < 4,'#7CFC00', '#FFA07A')}" class="spinner-twenty" name="spinner" value="0.1">
    </p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use *jQuery* `.change` function which will be triggered on `input` value change,

**But** in your case which you are using **spinner** when a value changed it add a new attribute to the input called `aria-valuenow=""` so you can't trigger on value change because there is `.value()` but no `.aria-valuenow()`,

So far I created new default input for testing and it worked greate, see the updated [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vtfqW/357/).

## Update

You could use `.on("spinstop",...)`, see the updated [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sc28/vtfqW/358/).

Comment: Thanks for the hints! You're correct, the `.change` wouldn't work on the spinner, but I found in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16620690/3976696)  that another event could be used: `.on("spinstop",...)`. See the updated [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sc28/vtfqW/358)  for a final working solution (i.e. conditional formatting on spinner `input`'s value). If you update your answer with the new change event I can mark it as accepted.

Comment: Well done! you are most welcome and btw I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The resources you link to are describing **server-side logic** (two different kinds, neither of which you appear to be using). They determine what HTML should be output before it leaves the server.

Browsers do not support logic in style attributes.

To achieve this you will need to write some JavaScript. You could binding an *Event Listener* to the element that fires when there is an *input* event, reads the `value` property of the element and then sets the `style.backgroundColor` property.